# Binding multiple radio buttons to one field in access database: saving and loading values back and forth

Tags: c#, database, data-binding, radio-button

I have 5 radio buttons (representing shirt sizes S-XXL) in a row that are binded to one field in an Access db.  They are part of a form that has info about each specific person in the db. I want to be able to, upon the load of each person, also populate the radio button according to their shirt size.  Is this possible? If so, any suggestions with code in C# would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Yes is possible to do this, in my company I use by this way:

When you create each radio, you need to specify the Tag property to the real value that you will go to save in the database, after, the bind needs to make a foreach to identify the value.

```
foreach (Control objControl in Controls)
                {
                    RadioButton objCurrentRadio = null;

                    if (objControl is RadioButton)
                    {
                        objCurrentRadio = (RadioButton)objControl;

                        if (objCurrentRadio == null || objCurrentRadio.Tag == null)
                            continue;

                        string sTag = (string)objControl.Tag;

                        if (sTag == _sSelectedItem)
                        {
                            objCurrentRadio.Checked = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            objCurrentRadio.Checked = false;
                        }

                        objCurrentRadio.TabStop = this.TabStop;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: also, where would I put this?

Comment: `_sSelectedItem` is the value from the DB.